# Connection between Lotus Notes and PostgreSQL

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, postgresql-9.3, lotus

I want to connect to a Postgres Database with Lotus Notes 8.5.3 in win32 server. I tried to install Pg odbc driver 9.3 and the odbc connection is successful when i launch it in odbcad32. But it doesn't work through the domino server with ndctest command , i have this message error : "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" . Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved , the odbccad32 where i should configure my ODBC connection should be in SysWOW64 and not in System32. I don't know why but it's Microsoft.

Comment: It's because it's a 32 bit driver,providing compatibility mode services for 32 bit code running on 64 bit windows. It's a perverse bit of opposite-land. In a 64 bit Windows OS, everything that's 32 bit goes into SysWOW64, which refers t ""System Win-On-Windows64)